# XSLT template match scope of data used for the selection

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, scope, match

I have an issue. I have some XML. I want to use template match for some repeating parts down the hierarchical structure. Part of my match condition is data from outside of the template match. How to achieve this?

I am using XSLT v3.0.

Sample data(much simpler than the actual data, but it should explain my situation):

```
<root>
  <source>Abc</source>
  <record>
    <key>1</key>
    <value>a</value>
  </record>
  <record>
    <key>1</key>
    <value>a</value>
  </record>
  <record>
    <key>2</key>
    <value>b</value>
  </record>
  <record>
    <key>3</key>
    <value>c</value>
  </record>
</root>
```

my template match condition would look like this:

```
<template match="record[key ="a"] and \root\source = "Abc">
```

Obviously, the part about record works, the part about \root\source does not. even when I want to use the \root\source value inside the template, it is blank. I understand this might be some scope limitation of XSLT. Is there **ANY** way to go around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain your conditions in words. In your example, `source` is a sibling of `record` - so it is not clear what is the relationship you are looking for. And also there is no `record` with `key ="a"` - so that's confusing.

Comment: And path steps are separated by `/` and not `\\`.

Comment: I know my description is very incomplete. The issue is i have inherited a project that was not touched for about 3 years. My xslt skills are basic. The shown data is overly simplified. The records themselves are about 10 elements deep from the root, the source element is only 2 elements deep. Based on another answer i have realized my issue with using the source element is in incorrect namespace usage in the xpath, this can not be shown in the data i have provided as i have thought the issue is somewhere else  and  i have provided 0 information about the namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (!) you want:

```
<xsl:template match="root[source = 'Abc']/record[key ='a']" >
```

which will match a `record` whose `key` value is `"a"` and has a `source` sibling whose value is `"Abc"`.

---

> even when I want to use the \root\source value inside the template, it is blank.

From within a template matching `record`, you can get the value of `source`  using any one of these expressions:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../source" />
```

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::source" />
```

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/source" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have realized my selection logic was incorrect by using 2 different xml tree positions in one [ ] instead of using as many [ ] as needed. I have unfortunately found i have trouble to use correct namespaces in my path . That is i believe the reason why i can not get the values. My oversimplified sample data does not show namespaces at all. My problem is not yet solved but i need to work on the namespaces first.